# Rogue Exception, System.InvalidOperationException, XNA

Tags: c#, exception, xna

My xna game has this "rogue" System.InvalidOperationException which only happens sometimes and seems to be triggered at random or at least something out of my control input wise. After pressing start and loading the first menu screen, (I used the GameStateManagement sample as the base for my game if that helps whatsoever) the game *sometimes* but not always throws a System.InvalidOperationException at the "in" part of "foreach (GameScreen screen in screens)" Full code for the method:

```
            /// <summary>
    /// Tells each screen to draw itself.
    /// </summary>
    public override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {

        foreach (GameScreen screen in screens) //exception thrown at the "in" part
        {
            if (screen.ScreenState == ScreenState.Hidden)
                continue;

            screen.Draw(gameTime);
        }
    }
```

I'm honestly clueless as to what triggers this exception because I'm not doing anything different from when it throws the exception and when it doesn't. I'm not exactly sure if this will help you but this is the exception details

```
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
   at GameStateManagement.ScreenManager.Draw(GameTime gameTime)
   at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.Draw(GameTime gameTime)
   at GameStateManagement.GameStateManagementGame.Draw(GameTime gameTime)
   at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.DrawFrame()
   at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.Tick()
   at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.HostIdle(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GameHost.OnIdle()
   at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.XboxGameHost.RunOneFrame()
   at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.XboxGameHost.Run()
   at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.RunGame(Boolean useBlockingRun)
   at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.Run()
   at GameStateManagement.Program.Main()
}   System.Exception {System.InvalidOperationException}
```

and this is the call stack:

```
>   GameStateManagementSample.exe!GameStateManagement.ScreenManager.Draw(Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GameTime gameTime) Line 338 + 0x33 bytes   C#
Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.dll!Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.Draw(Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GameTime gameTime) + 0x4d bytes  
GameStateManagementSample.exe!GameStateManagement.GameStateManagementGame.Draw(Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GameTime gameTime) Line 89 + 0x7 bytes   C#
Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.dll!Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.DrawFrame() + 0x6a bytes  
Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.dll!Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.Tick() + 0x2a9 bytes  
Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.dll!Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.HostIdle(object sender, System.EventArgs e) + 0x6 bytes   
Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.dll!Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GameHost.OnIdle() + 0x19 bytes 
Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.dll!Microsoft.Xna.Framework.XboxGameHost.RunOneFrame() + 0xc bytes 
Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.dll!Microsoft.Xna.Framework.XboxGameHost.Run() + 0x1b bytes    
Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.dll!Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.RunGame(bool useBlockingRun) + 0x9c bytes 
Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.dll!Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.Run() + 0x7 bytes 
GameStateManagementSample.exe!GameStateManagement.Program.Main() Line 108 + 0x6 bytes   C#
```

Thanks! Ivatrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your game code is modifying `screens` on some code path you haven't considered. Take a look at the documentation on [IEnumerator.MoveNext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerator.movenext.aspx).

> The collection was modified after the enumerator was created.

Comment: Just to clarify what I'm trying to find here, does this mean that "screens" was modified before "screen" was initialized?

Comment: Oops I meant after, not before.

Comment: OK ignore my previous comments I get what an enumerator is now, I'm still pretty new to programming :P I think I may have fixed it now! Although I can't know for sure because it wasn't an exception that consistently happened. What I did was think about where it caused the exception to figure out the why and I concluded that it only happened in the main menu screen, so I must of been changing something there. I looked at the difference between transitioning the main menu screen and other screens and found I was only using a null player index in the main menu which I wasn't doing in the other

Comment: screens. this caused the main menu instance of screen.playerindex to be null when it wasn't in the other screens which I think was the modification in the exception that was throwing the error! Hopefully I'm right, I'll be testing the game constantly today to make sure I don't see that exception again and I'll keep you updated if the exception still happens or if I think it's fixed :) Thanks! Ivatrix.

Comment: Ok so after the about 25th test through it gave me that darn exception again, back to the drawing board I go! Any more help that anyone can give me would be much appreciated :)